# Audit web part removal and restoring a webpart in a sharepoint 2010 wiki page

Tags: web-part, auditing, wiki-pages

One of my SP2010 wiki pages is suddenly missing a webpart, most probably due to  a human error of one of the users.
I tried to restore that webpart using the page versioning, but it has no impact or influence when it comes to webparts.

1. Is there any way to restore a page version together with a deleted web part?
2. Is there a way to audit who deletes a webpart? i couldn't find it in my audit logs.

Thanks,
Ariel

Answer (score 0):

Enable versioning and content approval on the pages library.

This way users are required to checkout files -> modify -> check-in -> Approval required.. you will have better control.

Also check the version history and see who modified the files recently. The missing webpart you can add it manually instead of restoring the page.